# Concurrent builds in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am very new to Jenkins. In my company we are moving build process from cruisecontrol.net to Jenkins. So I did all the set-up. Now what I need is, I want to trigger 3 downstream builds same time after the success of one upstream build.

Example: After success of A, it should trigger the build B,C,D.

Please let me know the way. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'Post-build Actions', add 'Build other projects'. A comma-separated list of projects can be entered. Also, you have the option of having it only trigger these jobs upon a stable build.

Click below for more details about this and other options:

[How to use Jenkins for Job Chaining and Visualizations](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jenkins-for-job-chaining-and-visualizations/)

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. I tried this way, in my situation we have to trigger 4 build same time. I used, build other projects  in post build and I included 4 projects here. But it is triggering only 2 builds in one-time. So could you please tell me if there is away to solve this. Thank you

Comment: how many Jenkins executors do you have? Maybe only 2? You can only do as many builds in parallel as you have executors...